# How to call service within loop angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
var g = [];
    ecs.get($routeParams.id)
      .then(function (data) {
        var east = data;

      for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        if (res[i].is_fine === true) {
          if(res[i].t == east.type){
            g.push(res[i].user_id);  
          }
        }
      }
});

var res = [{
                FruitId: 1,
                Name: 'Apple',
                Selected: false
            }, {
                FruitId: 2,
                Name: 'Mango',
                Selected: false
            }, {
                FruitId: 3,
                Name: 'Orange',
                Selected: false
            }];

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.g" ng-init='user.g=false'>
```

Why does it produce me error is_fine is undefined, when i remove my ecs.get service it works is_fine
Please take a look and suggest thanks a ton in advance

Comment: where do you define `res`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: IF that is your response, there is no `is_fine` key in that `res`

Comment: @sravan perfect thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you have `wrong reference` to the `keys` of the object

Since you have `Selected` as your boolean, you should take `Selected` instead of `is_fine` and `Name` instead of `type`

```
var g = [];
    ecs.get($routeParams.id)
      .then(function (data) {
        var east = data;

      for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        if (res[i].Selected === true) {
          if(res[i].Name == east.type){
            g.push(res[i].FruitId);  
          }
        }
      }
});

var res = [{
                FruitId: 1,
                Name: 'Apple',
                Selected: false
            }, {
                FruitId: 2,
                Name: 'Mango',
                Selected: false
            }, {
                FruitId: 3,
                Name: 'Orange',
                Selected: false
            }];
```

Comment: @Saurav, added the same as an answer. Please check